# iOS Login with cancel and success on storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xcode5, segue

This is my first iOS app and at this moment I'm struggling with Acccount / Login transitions on my storyboard.

What I'm trying to do is, If there is no logged user, display the login, otherwise display the account menu (Edit profile, My savings, and Logout).
Actually I'm achieving with this code on my AccountMenuViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (![self isLogged]) {
        [self presentLoginView];
    }    
}

#pragma mark - Login methods
- (BOOL)isLogged
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    return [[defaults objectForKey:@"loggedIn"] boolValue];
}

- (void)presentLoginView
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoginSegueId" sender:self];
}
```

When the user touch "Cancel login" I'm trying to redirect to my MainView, I've make a segue but the Tab Bar is not displayed.

And when the login is ok, Close the login view.

I want to know your advices and tips, What are the best practices with this scenario?

This is my Storyboard.

[image: MyStoryboard]

Answer (score 0):

First you should either make the login screen your rootViewController and just push to main view if

```
[self isLogged]==YES
```

or have the Login presented in a model fashion with the main view as a root, that way instead of a segue you can just dismiss it and the main view will be present underneath. you can also have the main view push the login and just hide the nav bar and use 'cancel login' as a sort of '< back' button that you would see on the nav bar by using the popViewController method..... also you can simplify the method:

```
- (BOOL)isLogged
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    return [[defaults objectForKey:@"loggedIn"] boolValue];
}
```

can be :

```
- (BOOL)isLogged
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loggedIn"];
}
```

hope i helped!

Comment: Hello 2020Deceptiononymous, Thanks for your help. Finally I'm using a library called AFPopupView https://github.com/AlvaroFranco/AFPopupView I've dropped the segue from the "Account Options" to "Login" and now I'm using NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: just be careful with 3rd party libraries bc sometimes the licenses restrict use. Most don't but some do. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I will keep in mind. Thanks for your advices. I will dig more on iOS. Cheers!